# How to highlight object on the picture

Tags: java, android

I set a picture as background in my main activity with some objects like home.gif, car.gif, dog.gif, etc. All object files are transparent.
I want to highlight this objects that user can interact with it.

I could not found examples in web how to get this effect. So I am asking here.

I would be grateful if you could help me.

Thank you for your time and consideration!

Ciao, Szymon

Comment: Your question isn't clear, Elaborate what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the border of the transparent images in an activity?

Then in selector of that view you just add a pressed state which has borders set.

Comment: Yes :D I want to show the highlight border of the specific transparent element. How can I do it? Can you share me the xml code? Thanks!

Comment: I have not checked if this works. But try this code in onClick() method
`v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_drawable);`. Where v is the ImageView

Comment: You need to set the 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
in your "border_drawable" drawable. Hope this works